# Join two tables to populate a viewModel with a nested collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two tables `Client` and `Account`:

```
public partial class Client
{
    public Client()
    {
        this.Account = new HashSet<Account>();
        this.Doc = new HashSet<Doc>();
    }

    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Account> Account { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Doc> Doc { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public partial class Account
{
    public Account()
    {
        this.Doc = new HashSet<Doc>();
    }

    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Fk_ClientId { get; set; }

    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Doc> Doc { get; set; }
}
```

Data looks like this:

*Client:*

```
ClientID     Name
   1         Ben
   2         Joseph
```

*Account:*

```
AccountID     Name             Fk_ClientId
   1         BenAccount1           1
   2         BenAccount2           1
   3         JosephAccount1        2
   4         JosephAccount2        2
   5         JosephAccount3        2
```

I've written the following query:

```
var query = from clnt in db.Client
                        join acnt in db.Account 
                             on clnt.ClientId equals acnt.Fk_ClientId
                        select new SearchViewModel
                        {
                            Name = clnt.Name,
                            AccountNumber = //don't know what I should write here
                        };
```

**The result is should be look like this:**
[image]

My viewModel is `SearchViewModel`:

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<string> AccountNumber { get; set; }        
}
```

I can imitate result, if I create instance of `SearchViewModel` manually:

```
List<SearchViewModel> searchVM = new List<SearchViewModel>()
{ 
   new SearchViewModel(){Name="Ben", AccountNumber = new List<string>() { "BenAccount1", 
           "BenAccount2" } }, 
   new SearchViewModel(){Name="Joseph", AccountNumber = new List<string>() {  
           "JosephAccount1", "JosephAccount2", "JosephAccount3" } },                    
};
```

How to make a such result using `linq`?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are looking for is the `Groupjoin` method. 
In query syntax it looks like this:

```
var query = from clnt in db.Client
            join acnt in db.Account on clnt.ClientId equals acnt.Fk_ClientId into accounts
            select new SearchViewModel
            {
                Name = clnt.Name,
                AccountNumber = accounts.Select(account => account.Name)
            };
```

Comment: man, you're awesome! Accept your answer in 5 minutes!:) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var result = db.Client.Select(client => new SearchViewModel
{
    Name = client.Name,
    AccountNumber = client.Account.Select(account => account.Name).ToList()
}).ToList();
```